# a href hover not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give a button in my site a different hover color to the other links but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to do so with CSS and ere's what I've got so far:

CSS:

```
.next-button {
a:hover { color:#3399FF; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="next-button" align="right"><font size="2"><a href="#">Next</a></font></p>
```

Why is this link staying the same color as the others?

Comment: .next-button a:hover 
{ color:#3399FF; 
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uraqoJES/1/edit)

```
.next-button a:hover {
    color:#39f; 
}
```

you just had an extra `{`

Answer (score 0):

```
.next-button a:hover { 
color:#3399FF; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hover properties is not associated with div class you've created

```
.next-button a:hover { 
   color:#3399FF; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.next-button a:hover { 
color:#3399FF;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="next-button" text-align="right">
    <font size="2">
        <a href="#">Next</a>
    </font>
</p>
```